# How to choose a random element of a Java array if the length of the array is unknown

Tags: java, arrays, cookies, random

I have an array of cookies:

```
Cookie[] ncs = request.getCookies();
```

They have names like "n1","n2"..."n40".."nk"

How do I choose a random cookie without taking into account other cookies like "username" etc.?

Comment: Iterate over all cookies, check their names, store only those with `nX` format, and pick one only from the store ones. Of if you are guaranteed to have all `n1, .., nX` cookies find max value of `X` and pick random value in range `[1,max]`.

Comment: @Pshemo You should post this as an answer with some basic examples, because this is (an easy) way of achieving the goal.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the technique shown below to get a random cookie.

```
Cookie[] ncs = request.getCookies();
int randomInt = (int)(Math.random() * ncs.length);
Cookie randomCookie = ncs[randomInt];
```

Comment: This answer seems to be wrong, for a few reasons: (1) it doesn't compile since `ncs` is array, so it doesn't have `size()` method, but `length` field; (2) it uses all cookies, but @DmitryMahliui said in question "*without taking into account other cookies like "username" etc.*". I don't know why OP accepted this answer.